# Changing height of rows in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I compared a tinymce textarea filled with words in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox of course the tinymce textarea was from the same code, so it should be the same on both browsers.

However, it turned out that the textarea in Firefox has rows with bigger height.

Here's the image:

[image: This is my image]

Now here I have only two rows and the difference may not seem that big. But, I work with larger data and with many rows, the difference is more visible.

Is there a way to fix this? I want to fix the height of the rows for Mozilla Firefox. For Chrome it's good.

Answer (score 0):

While initializing you can give

```
tinyMCE.init({
   mode : "exact",
   height:100
});
```

or like

```
$('#my_txt_id').height('100px');
```

here it is the id of textarea for which you gave tinyMCE

Comment: And how does this help for the tinymce to remain the same in Chrome and change ROW (not textarea) height in Firefox?